# Unsure about java JDK for Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, java

I have done a yum search java before installing anything to see if may have already. It comes back with the following:

```
libreadline-java-javadoc.i686 : Javadoc for libreadline-java
libvirt-java-devel.noarch : Compressed Java source files for libvirt-java
libvirt-java-javadoc.noarch : Java documentation for libvirt-java
lpg-java-compat.noarch : Compatibility Java runtime library for LPG 1.x
pki-java-tools.noarch : Certificate System - PKI Java-Based Tools
pki-java-tools-javadoc.noarch : Certificate System - PKI Java-Based Tools
ppl-java-javadoc.i686 : Javadocs for ppl-java
java-1.5.0-gcj.i686 : JPackage runtime compatibility layer for GCJ
java-1.5.0-gcj-devel.i686 : JPackage development compatibility layer for GCJ
java-1.5.0-gcj-javadoc.i686 : API documentation for libgcj
java-1.5.0-gcj-src.i686 : Source files for libgcj
java-1.6.0-openjdk.i686 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo.i686 : OpenJDK Demos
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.i686 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.i686 : OpenJDK API Documentation
java-1.6.0-openjdk-src.i686 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-demo.i686 : OpenJDK Demos
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.i686 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.i686 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
```

So does this mean I have it installed or is this just some general information pertaining to what java can run on the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple answer, probably not.

Running the command `yum search java` just shows you possible packages that match your search criteria. To see what's installed you need to search using either `rpm` or query using `yum list installed`

#### Examples

*rpm*

```
$ rpm -aq | grep -E "jdk|java"
```

*yum*

```
$ yum list installed java* jdk*
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                                 1:1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc19                                            @updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64                                           1:1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc19                                            @updates 
javahelp2.noarch                                                          2.0.05-13.fc19                                                     @fedora  
javamail.noarch                                                           1.4.3-16.fc19                                                      @fedora  
javapackages-tools.noarch                                                 0.15.0-2.fc19                                                      @updates 
jdk.x86_64                                                                2000:1.7.0_45-fcs                                                  installed
```

So in both outputs we can see that I have packages "java" and "jdk" installed. The reason I have 2 types of packages installed is because one is the Open JDK package. These are the RPM's named "Java*".

The version of Java distributed by Oracle/Sun are called JDK, these are the "jdk*" RPMs. This is the Java Developers Kit.

You also might have the run-time environment installed (JRE), these are typically called "jre*".

Comment: I did get the rpm and installed it easily enough once I knew which version to choose.